# Join of of multiple streams with the Python SDK

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I would like to join multiple streams on a common key and trigger a result either as soon as all of the streams have contributed at least one element or at the end of the window. CoGroupByKey seems to be the appropriate building block, but there does not seem to be a way to express the early trigger condition (count trigger applies per input collection)?

Comment: What did you end up doing? A new answer would be welcomed

Comment: We first implemented using CoGroupByKey, but lack the ability to trigger early (only on watermark). But now support for state and timers was added to the Python SDK and it is also supported by the Flink runner that we are using (Beam release 2.9). So we are going to switch to state and timer based implementation.

Comment: Wow great news, the docs still says Python state & timers APIs are not supported for all runners https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-streaming/   Thanks for pointing it out, I see it in the release notes. I'm using the DataflowRunner hopefully that will add support soon. It would be a game changer to have stateful processing

Answer (score 2):

I believe `CoGroupByKey` is implemented as `Flatten + GroupByKey` under the hood. Once multiple streams are flattened into one, data-driven trigger (or any other triggers) won't have enough control to achieve what you want.

Instead of using `CoGroupByKey`, you can use `Flatten` and `StatefulDoFn` that fills an object backed by `State` for each key. Also in this case, `StatefulDoFn` would have the chance to decide what to do when stream A has 2 elements arrived but stream B doesn't have any element yet.

Comment: When using the Java SDK, this would absolutely be the best solution! User state and timers are very powerful and address this and many other use cases that are difficult/impractical with higher level windowing. But unfortunately there is no support for stateful DoFn in the Python SDK yet.

Comment: oops, I totally missed "the python sdk". You can probably perform join with the help of some external storage (e.g. bigtable)?

Comment: Yes, using stateless function with external storage may be a workaround.

Comment: If you know that at most one element per key comes per stream, you could trigger this on First(AfterCount(N), EndOfWindow). The intent of DataDriven triggers was to generalize AfterCount to accept an arbitrary T -> Boolean combiner, which when implemented could replace the AfterCount(N) with a something that waits until all N independent streams have at least one element (though this gets tricky if the ordering is e1, e2, e1 vs. e1, e1, e2 for a 2-way join).

Comment: You could also do this with a custom WindowFn, like Sessions, but moving the end of the window earlier once it's "full" (i.e. has representatives from every stream).

Comment: BigTable is also not yet supported in the Python SDK :( 
@robertwb how would you implement moving the window earlier? Would love to see a separate answer for that

Answer (score 2):

Another potential solution that comes to mind is (a stateless) DoFn that filters the CoGBK results to remove those that don't have at least one occurrence for each joined stream. For the end of window result (which does not have the same restriction), it would then be necessary to have a parallel CoGBK and its result would not go through the filter. I don't think there is a way to tag results with the trigger that emitted it?

Comment: This only works if your trigger and processing logic is compatible with using an accumulating trigger. This allows you to then have a stateless DoFn that filters all early firings which don't have at least one element on each stream. I'm not sure whether the PaneInfo in Python exposes whether its early, on time, or late though.